# Template argument for template type parameter must be a type?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I am trying to call this class constructor:

```
template<typename T>
ListNode<T>::ListNode(SkipListKind kind, const T& key){
     key = SkipListKey<T>(kind, key); // A private member of the class
}
```

I call it like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<ListNode<T>(SkipListKind::NegInf, T{})>);
```

I get this error:
template argument for template type parameter must be a type

Can someone please explain why? Thanks!

Comment: And GOD written that message in your cereals that morning, didn't you read it? _Thou shalt keep your angle bracket (`<>`) balance clean, as you do for all those other bracket types!_

Answer (score 4):

Whatever goes inside the outer set of angle brackets is the template argument. `std::shared_ptr` takes a type as its template parameter. What you have inside the outer set of angle brackets is not a type; it's a type followed by constructor arguments.

You probably want:

```
std::make_shared<ListNode<T>>(SkipListKind::NegInf, T{})
```

The `std::make_shared` function template takes a type as its template parameter and then forwards its arguments to the type's constructor, finally returning a `std::shared_ptr` to the newly constructed object.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
std::shared_ptr<ListNode<T>(SkipListKind::NegInf, T{})>);
                                                 //   ^
```

You probably meant to do this:

```
std::make_shared<ListNode<T>>(SkipListKind::NegInf, T{});
                         // ^
```